# Hold gesture doesn't work without a little move

Tags: windows-phone-8, monogame, gestures

I ported some code to MonoGame and I got a problem: A hold gesture doesn't happen until I make a move, so in order to get a hold gesture I need press finger/mouse, wait for some time and then move finger/mouse a little bit. This issue reproduces on both Device and Emulator. I don't have this problem when use XNA library on the same device.

The code is simple

```
 while (TouchPanel.IsGestureAvailable)
 {
       GestureSample originalGesture = TouchPanel.ReadGesture();
       ...
```

Is there any common solution except for emulating a hold gesture by processing TouchLocation?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just check the TouchLocation.State for Pressed.  If its pressed for more than 1 draw cycle then perhaps assume its a hold gesture?

Thats what I do in my monogame code, check TouchLocation.State for TouchLocationState.Pressed and TouchLocationState.Released.